# Getting header information from a request of a page in flutter web

Tags: flutter

I've this code in flutter 3

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      ...
      routes: {
        '/uno' : (context) => Uno(),
        '/due' : (context) => Due(),
      },
      initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        switch (settings.name){
          case '/uno':
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Uno()
            );
          case '/due':
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Due()
          );
        }
      } ,
      home: const Uno(),
    );
  }
```

In flutter web I use the link http://localhost:3267/#/uno or http://localhost:3267/#/due
to access to the APP. Is there a way to get the header or payload information of this request?